# Change folded text color based on regex in vim?

Tags: vim

This question has been asked in the past not sure if there have been any new solutions, updates, or alternatives since?

I want to change the color of the folded dictionaries to white and the functions leave them blue. The work around for now is that I have been putting 'DIC': at the start of the fold to easily identify dictionaries. It would be nice for dictionary folds be white.

[image: DIC is a way to identify]

Comment: If I was you, I'd ask on [vi & Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry, all folds are indistinguishable. What you see after closing fold is just a replacement text and doesn't really "exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one highlight group for folds:

```
:help hl-folded
```

and userland commands and functions like `:help :match` or `:help matchadd()` only work on the actual *content* of the buffer so what you are asking for is currently impossible.